# A short trip to Canada

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration

I will be traveling to Canada with my family for a week. My kid's US passport is due to expire 2 weeks after the date we plan on returning back to the US. Will we be able to take our trip?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Canada has no requirements as to the validity of passports, as long as they are valid for the length of your stay.

If you weren't US citizens you might have your stay specifically limited in writing to the duration of your passports, but as Americans, you will be just fine getting re-admitted to the US with expired passports, so this won't be an issue.